# Cross compile linker LTHUNK0 error

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, beagleboneblack

I'm having a problem trying to cross-compile a wxWidgets sample program.
The host is a PC running Debian (a VM if it matters), and the target is a BeagleBone Black (BBB) also running Debian.

As a background note, I'm a C/C++ programmer, but strictly in the embedded and Windows world.  I know just enough about Linux to be able to break it.

I've successfully cross-compiled a simple C++ program, and it runs fine on the BBB.  I used the tutorial from Derek Molloy to get Eclipse installed and cross-compiling:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzZHcH5quow

Next, I downloaded wxWidgets and compiled it on the BBB (not on the PC) into static libraries.  Here's the config I used:

```
../configure --enable-debug --enable-debug_info --disable-shared --enable-stl --enable-sockets --enable-gif --enable-pcx --with-libpng --with-libjpeg
```

It compiled fine.  I then built a bunch of the demos and samples and they all compiled and ran fine on the BBB.

Next I wanted to be able to cross-compile so I could use some decent development tools.
I copied all the wxWidgets libraries over to the PC, then I also copied all the include directories I would need (GTK, cairo, pango, glib...) and their libraries (from the BBB to the PC).

After a lot of trial and error, I finally got it all to compile and link.  Almost.

The linker is giving the following errors (5 of them, all very similar):

> `.LTHUNK0' referenced in section
>   `.text._ZN17wxWindowWithItemsI9wxControl15wxItemContainerED1Ev[_ZN17wxWindowWithItemsI9wxControl15wxItemContainerED1Ev]'
>   of 
>   /home/dave/BeagleBoneResources/lib/wx/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.a(corelib_choiccmn.o):
>   defined in discarded section 
>   `.text._ZN17wxWindowWithItemsI9wxControl15wxItemContainerED2Ev[_ZN17wxWindowWithItemsI9wxControl15wxItemContainerED5Ev]'
>   of 
>   /home/dave/BeagleBoneResources/lib/wx/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.a(corelib_choiccmn.o)

I see it's referencing libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.a, which is one of the wxWidgets libraries I built on the BBB.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?  I sure hope I don't have to rebuild all the dependencies with the cross compiler, there's a LOT of them, and I wouldn't even know where to start.